# Are there any advantages to using mongodb over mysql if said mongo db were used without embedded documents?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, normalization, database-schema

I'm using a php framework with a mongodb adapter that doesn't currently comprehend embedded documents as a Model/association relationship.  After reading about mongodb for a few days it seems that you should use embedded documents for objects that are most often displayed together.  This makes a lot of sense to me.  It was said during one mongo schema talk that a collection of many small documents can negate some of the advantages of mongo over an RDBMS.

In searching stackoverflow and beyond, I can't seem to see what advantages exist, if any, when deploying mongodb into an environment where it is implemented with a reasonably normalized schema like you'd find in a traditional RDBMS.

**Are there still advantages to using MongoDB when used in this way?  Scaling?  Performance?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "reasonably normalized" you mean that you need information from one table to filter the information from another table (i.e. a join), then mongo is going to work against you. In a SQL database you can easily get the info from multiple tables with a single query. In mongo you'll need multiple queries to get data from multiple collections. Any speed advantage mongo gives you in pulling from a single collection will quickly be negated by making multiple round trips to the database.

Comment: The framework I'm currently using, CakePHP 2, seems to rarely use joins even with SQL dbs.  The relationships between Models are managed in the app, not on the db.  I guess then the question becomes: is a round trip to mongo faster than a round trip to mysql (query only, not connection+query).

Comment: In that situation I would have to say that you're probably still better off with SQL, but not by much. I haven't done any speed tests, but people have been working on making SQL DBs fast and efficient for a lot longer than mongo, and this situation doesn't play to mongo's strengths, so my guess is that mongo would be slower.

Comment: I take that back. This is playing to mongo's strengths. Mongo is very fast at dealing with a single collection, but SQL is more for relationships. Those relationships come with overhead, even if you aren't really using them, simply because that's what the DB is optimized for.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some advantages that MongoDb might give you (depending on your usecase):

- **Schemaless**: More flexible if document structure is modified later.
- **Performance**: MongoDB utilizes the RAM available very well making it very performant
- **Easy replication**: Replication is easy to setup
- **Sharding/Clustering**: MongoDB is designed with sharding in mind. It is easy to setup and doesn't require experts.
- **Map/Reduce**: If you happen to need this, there is built-in support.
- **Javascript**: Intuitive to use if you already know Javascript (and who doesn't nowadays :) )

MongoDB website has a good [list of casestudies of production deployments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments).

Comment: You may want to edit your first bullet point to read **Schemaless**, without the 'c' it takes on a rather different connotation.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has replication and sharding built in.

These are things that can be done with MySQL.

The downside is the learning curve and lack of programmers that know it.

If it's just for you, it would be fun as a learning project.

If this is for a larger project, you'll need to weigh the lack of MongoDB programmers and learning curve against popularity of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing my University dissertation project with MySQL first then  thought to give a shot to MongoDB to improve performance. Rewriting code was really easy and straightforward with Jongo. Production has been really smooth.

Unfortunately performance were terrible. I am not particularly skilled with MongoDB queries, but I believe I did quite a lot of research: I have used map reduce, I have used the aggregation framework, $limit and all that stuff... when at same stage I got the message: "request heap use exceeded 10% of physical RAM" I really gave up and delivered the MySQL version.

For me it's really a shame because I was working so hard to make it work the best way possible with MongoDB (as a University project stands out if you do something different). However I think I will continue study MongoDB in future, but for the moment I stick to performance (or better what I can make perform).

I hope my comment will not offend MongoDB fans, but this is my experience.